# Lack of Arduino StackExchange logo?

Tags: discussion, site-design

This is more than likely an obvious question but I would still like to confirm my suspicion or perhaps I'm completely wrong and there could be something I'm ignorant about the processes behind StackExchange operations.

Cut to the chase, **why isn't a logo or banner for this website?** I know we're out of the beta stage but every SE branch out there that is not a beta has their own website (okay, I might have some confirmation bias but you know what I mean, right?). Is it due to the fact of possible copyright infringement if had their logo or pictures of their products on this website? I'm assuming that this place is an *unofficial* Arduino supported website so perhaps that could explain the lack of branding for this website. The main reason why I ask is to fulfill my own curiosity. I'm not suggesting a call for action or anything.

I mean, even Raspberry Pi SE has *something* for their website and they don't have the company logo for what I presume the same reason.

Comment: [dsp.se] was the last site that got its design, and it was on October **2016**. Since then, [there's no new site design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290359/how-long-until-graduated-sites-get-a-new-site-design-and-increased-privileges-th), and since site logo is one of site design elements...

Comment: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our designers from earlier this week: [Custom Arduino Community design and logo - Information gathering](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2716/80022) :)

Answer (score 2):

It takes times for a theme to be developed, there is a intermediate stage where the beta skin is still used (without actual beta branding) while the graphics designers get around to taking it out of the backlog.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Ratchet Freak's answer](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2535/10794) the Stack Exchange team wait until a site goes live (from Beta) before they even start on working out a logo and theme. And there is a backlog, quite a considerable one, I believe.

Looking on the bright side, the limits for [privileges](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) are not increased until the theme is developed. Compare us to [Electronics Stack Exchange privileges](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) for example.

So in many ways, it is in everyone's interests to have them take their time. You get access to somewhat higher moderation tools at a lower reputation level.

Answer (score 0):

Just to back up what has already been said; [Ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/) is an example of another site that has graduated from Beta who is also waiting on a logo.